# Programa para mostrar a quantidade de maiúsculas mostra apenas a quantidade de minúsculas

Tags: c, array

Escrevi um código para receber um arranjo de char e retornar a quantidade de letras maiúsculas, mas ele está fazendo o oposto ( retornando a quantidade de minúsculas ) e não sei por que.

```
void Questao4 ()
{   
    //definir dado
    char* cadeia ;
    cadeia = (char*) malloc( 20* sizeof (char)); 

     int i = 0;

    //identificar
    printf ( "EXEMPLO0413 - Metodo03 - v1.0\n" );

    //declaracao e entrada
    do
    {
        printf ( "Entre com uma cadeia de caracteres ( 0 para sair )\n " );
        scanf ( " %c", &cadeia[i]);
        fflush (stdin);
        getchar();
        i++;
    }
    while ( cadeia[i-1] != '0' );

    //saida
    printf ( "Na cadeia de caracteres apresentada, ha' [%d] maiusculas !!\n" ,contamaiuscula ( cadeia ) );
}


int contamaiuscula ( char x[])
{
    //definir dado
    int numerodemaiusculas = 0;
    int i = 0;

    //contagem de maiusculas
    while ( x[i] != '\0')
    {
        if ( x[i] >= 'A' && x[i] >= 'Z' )
        {
            numerodemaiusculas ++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return ( numerodemaiusculas );
}
```

Comment: Encontrei...erro imbecil. (x[ i ] <= 'Z')

Answer (score 2):

essa linha esta errada no seu código

```
 if ( x[i] >= 'A' && x[i] >= 'Z' )
```

so trocar e colocar assim:

```
if ( x[i] >= 'A' && x[i] <= 'Z' )
```